# Print Text(Codes) on Label stickers on PDF file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, itext

I have Generated codes which I have to print on the pdf file. I have tried using iTextSharp here is what I tried, Also added images so that it would be clear to understand

```
string l_strDomainName = "Example.com\n";

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5f, 10f, 30f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

pdfDoc.Open();

float[] widths = new float[] { 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 2f };
float[] widths1 = new float[] { 12f, 8f };


Chunk domainname = new Chunk(l_strDomainName, new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 6f, Font.ITALIC, Color.RED));

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
table.SetWidths(widths);
foreach (var item in CodeList)
{
    if (item.ToString().Trim() != "")
    {

        PdfPCell C1R1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(domainname + item + "\n", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 6f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        C1R1.Border = 1;
        C1R1.FixedHeight = 25f;
        C1R1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        C1R1.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        table.AddCell(C1R1);
    }
    else if (item.ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        table.AddCell("Used");
    }
}
if ((CodeList.Count) % 9 < 9)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 9 - (CodeList.Count) % 9; rows++)
    {
        table.AddCell("");
    }
}
pdfDoc.Add(table);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

And the Output is as follows
[image: Printed Codes]

My Question is I wanted to print this Codes inside rectangular boxes like the stickers on A4 size page.So that it can be handed over to the customers. As follows
[image: Pdf template]

Is their any way how can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried adding this -  PdfContentByte cb=writer.DirectContent;
                cb.RoundRectangle(u 100f, 50f, 20f);
                cb.Stroke();

Comment: Just an FYI, the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` will eventually create corrupt PDFs for you so just get rid of it. The `Document` class is a utility wrapper class and doesn't have a physical form. To say another way, it is not a PDF and never will be a PDF, but it does help make them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you help me by providing some websites link where I could learn more related to this.

Comment: If you want to learn about iText I'd recommend [reading the book](http://itextpdf.com/book/). The thing I mentioned is just general .Net. Besides the fact that `Document` doesn't represent a PDF, `Response.Write(object)` will never "know" what `object` really is and how to transform it into bytes so it will always just call `ToString()` on it.